# How can I get CK-editor to properly render special characters pasted from Word?

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor

I have configured a ck-editor in my app.
I'm trying to paste a text with special character from word documento into my ck-editor.
When I paste it, it display content properly.Here is the portion of text I use:

Show ⟨,⟩ .

Only after I persist the content of the ck-editor in mysql database,
is saved and shown as:

```
<p>Show &lang;??,??&rang;</p>
```

Aparently everything persists well, the parenthesis, except from the special character and symbols.
When I re-enter in edit mode in my ck-editor it also display with the questions marks.

My ck-editor does not have MATH jax library, I tried installing the pluggin but it stills renders as questions marks.

Should I implement some kind of sanitizer?
I also added the f math function into the special chars of the ck-editor (so that it recognize the html entity ƒ ) but again, it is always displaying as question marks.

Please advice.
Thank you.